# My snake game is operating very slowly. Is there any way to optimize it?

Tags: java

I have had a persistent issue of my snake game running slowly as the snake gets larger. I have narrowed it down to this block of code that is causing the problems:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < snake.size(); i++) {
    if(xCoor == snake.get(i).getxCoor() && yCoor == snake.get(i).getyCoor()) {
        if(i != snake.size() - 1) {
            stop();
            tries = 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the collision detection of the snake's head hitting the snake's body. I haven't been able to think of another way to optimize this besides removing it, which removes the core of the game. I think the issue that this runs each tick. I could change off from using ticks, but I have no idea how to start doing that.

**EDIT:** Here is how I have my game timing set up:

```
public void tick() {
    if(snake.size() == 0) {
        b = new BodyPart(xCoor, yCoor, 10);
        snake.add(b);
        }
    ticks++;
    if(ticks > 750000) {

    }
}
```

**EDIT2:** Thread.sleep(60) worked wonders! My stop() method just doesn't work anymore, but all it really did was set running to false, so I just did that manually on anything that ended the game.

Comment: What type of data type is `snake`?

Comment: If I'm understanding your question correctly, it's an ArrayList

Comment: There doesn't look to be any glaring issues with this code. Even looping 1000 times shouldn't be a deal breaker for being slow. You will likely need to add more code to help bring some context to this question.

Comment: @ug_ I have my tickrate at 750,000 = 1 frame. I can definitely post more though.

Comment: @jlars789: Yep that was the question.  A linked list would be much slower for random access as you're doing (barring anything fancy from the runtime), so wanted to make sure.

Comment: @MarkPeters Thanks for the concern! I am still trying to find which one is better for what situations. Glad I picked ArrayList here

Comment: By tickrate, do you mean you're running your core game loop 750000 times *per frame*?  That's much more than a human could reasonably ever notice or react to, so it certainly has no need to run that fast.  In general human reaction time is measured in the scale of 1-20 ms, so running a game at 200 fps would be above what any human could discern, and handling input/computations any more than 1000 times/second would be overkill.

Comment: @MarkPeters It seems like the higher the number goes, the slower it gets. I tried 500,000 and it was very quick. I can try lowering the tick rate.

Comment: @jlars789 Then what's wrong with setting your tick rate lower? Even 500,000 is way too high.

Comment: @jlars789 Most games run **way** under 500,000 tick. Popular FPS games will run at 100 or so and to give some context Minecraft is defaulted at 20. Note: tick rate != FPS

Comment: @pkpnd I updated the post showing how my game timing works. I tried setting it to 1000 and the snake hit the wall before I could react.

Comment: @jlars789: We're not getting the full picture of what you mean by `tick()` here.  Are you calling `tick()` in a loop as fast as possible (and then doing something every 750000 ticks)?  You should avoid that approach and use something like `Thread.sleep(20)` to sleep for 20 ms.  Otherwise you're keeping the CPU busy for no reason, and the number of ticks between actual updates would vary from CPU to CPU.

Comment: @MarkPeters That's exactly what tick() is. I'm not extremely keen on trashing a lot of my code and using things I'm not comfortable with, so would creating a value that is added to everytime ticks hits 750,000 be a good alternative to Thread.sleep(20)?

Comment: @jlars789: Not really.  It's important to yield the CPU when not in use, or you'll run into all sorts of performance problems (as well as melt the CPU...well not quite).  Big changes aren't required here, just instead of doing something every 750000 times, do it *every* time but do a `Thread.sleep(20)` as the last thing you do in `tick()`.

Comment: @MarkPeters Okay, I'll mess around with it, thank you very much!

Comment: @jlars789 Your notion of "tick rate" is the opposite of its usual meaning. In your code `if(ticks > X) {`, the value `X` is *not* the tick rate, but rather a measure of delay between actions. Increasing `X` will slow down the game (greater delay between actions). But as Mark Peters said, you should definitely be using a sleep call on every iteration of `tick()` and do away with the "count to 750000" logic.

Comment: @pkpnd Ah, my mistake. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following approaches:

1.You could create a Map or Set of (x,y) co-ordinates which are already occupied and check against it. This would be updated much less frequently than access.

2.You could create a two-dimensional array of boolean for each board position. Checking would be very fast. Updating would take some time. It depends on the relative frequencies on which the two occur.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I feel like both of these options would require a pretty big rehaul of how my game is currently setup

Comment: How often are you calling the collision detection routine? Is it per tick or per movement?

Comment: It's per movement